# Do ISO hashes guarantee safety?

Tags: iso, malware

I understand that checking the hashes for the Ubuntu isos is important to verify the integrity and authenticity of your download. If the hash matches and the gpg signature verifies the hash files does this guarantee that the ISO is safe and not infected? I remember when Linux Mint was hacked one of the things they said was to check the hashes. Does this mean that if a virus was on my computer and it tried to infect my Ubuntu ISO that it would change the sha256sum hashes?

Thanks!

Comment: any change to the file will change the checksum hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the PGP signatures are verified and the signed hashes match, that means the ISOs were created by the Ubuntu teams' build process. Nothing tampered the data while you downloaded it. However, this doesn't say anything about the build process itself. *That* could be compromised and spewing malware.

It does, however, guarantee that something on your system didn't modify the ISOs. The signatures can't be faked in a practical sense.